# How to load a model from a directory model of vendor in Codeigniter 4

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

First... I'm sorry for my bad grammar, but i'm still looking for my answer, but didn't find a good solution for beginner like me. I already looking over this place, there's a similar post, but didn't explain well.

My objective:
I want to redirect pages to admin menu whenever the "remember me" activated using [myth auth](https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth) function. I already found the way, but it's bad in practical.

Problem:
I want to load LoginModel made by myth auth into my basecontroller, but the LoginModel just separate away in another directory called "vendor".

Thanks in advance

I already tried by writing this command inside my Basecontroller (locate in app/Controllers)

```
$this->loginModel = new Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel;
```

It always give me error with this message "Class 'App\Controllers\Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel' not found".

Answer (score 1):

I think adding a backslash in front of `Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel` will solve the problem.

Change

`$this->loginModel = new Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel;`

to

`$this->loginModel = new \Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel;`

Without the backslash CI is looking for the class in the `App\Controller` namespace, as defined at the top of the BaseController file.
With the backslash it is looking for it in the global namespace (something like the root directory for classes).

If you look at the LoginModel file, you should see `namespace Myth\Auth\Models;` right at the top of the file. Think of this as the directory of the class.

You can also make use of the keyword `use`:

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use Myth\Auth\Models; // kind of adding a directory 

abstract class BaseController extends Controller
{
    
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->loginModel = new LoginModel();
        
    }
}
```

Without adding `use` you would need to write the full path.

`$this->loginModel = new \Myth\Auth\Models\LoginModel;`

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear. Maybe looking into Namespaces might help you understand it better.